# Grid with unknown number of cells of unknown widths in CSS

Tags: css, css-grid

Suppose we have a responsive grid container with indefinite number of child cells. Cells' widths and heights vary. Using only CSS (probably CSS Grid), how can we create such grid, that number of  columns / rows and the width / height of each column / row is determined dynamically based on the container's size (without overflowing it) and cells' sizes in one of the following two ways:

1. Width / height for each column / row is determined based on the widest / tallest cell in that column / row,
2. Width / height for all the columns / rows is determined based on the widest / tallest cell in the grid?

When applied to column width, these two cases loosely correspond to, respectively, automatic and fixed layout algorithms for tables. Except we don't know the number of columns and rows; it needs to be somehow determined automatically.

The following examples demonstrate these two cases applied to column width. For each case there are two possible flow directions: row or column. Note that in the examples we had to set the number of columns and their sizes specifically. I would like those to be determined automatically.

Please try to replicate these examples in your answer without setting the exact number of columns, rows and any widths or heights.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 3px solid teal;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.flex {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
  width: min-content;
}
.fixed {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 33.33%);
  width: 28em;
}
.column {
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.cell {
  padding: 1em;
  background: pink;
  border: 1px dashed teal;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

h3:not(:first-of-type) {
  margin-top: 3em;
}
```

```html
<h3>Flexible column width. Flow in rows</h3>
<div class="container flex row">
 <div class="cell">One</div>
 <div class="cell">Two</div>
 <div class="cell">Buckle my shoe</div>
 <div class="cell">Three</div>
 <div class="cell">Four</div>
 <div class="cell">Knock at the door</div>
 <div class="cell">Five</div>
 <div class="cell">Six</div>
</div>

<h3>Flexible column width. Flow in columns</h3>
<div class="container flex column">
 <div class="cell">One</div>
 <div class="cell">Two</div>
 <div class="cell">Buckle my shoe</div>
 <div class="cell">Three</div>
 <div class="cell">Four</div>
 <div class="cell">Knock at the door</div>
 <div class="cell">Five</div>
 <div class="cell">Six</div>
</div>

<h3>Fixed column width. Flow in rows</h3>
<div class="container fixed row">
 <div class="cell">One</div>
 <div class="cell">Two</div>
 <div class="cell">Buckle my shoe</div>
 <div class="cell">Three</div>
 <div class="cell">Four</div>
 <div class="cell">Knock at the door</div>
 <div class="cell">Five</div>
 <div class="cell">Six</div>
</div>

<h3>Fixed column width. Flow in columns</h3>
<div class="container fixed column">
 <div class="cell">One</div>
 <div class="cell">Two</div>
 <div class="cell">Buckle my shoe</div>
 <div class="cell">Three</div>
 <div class="cell">Four</div>
 <div class="cell">Knock at the door</div>
 <div class="cell">Five</div>
 <div class="cell">Six</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not possible with CSS-Grid or, for that matter, any current layout method. Row heights cannot be equalised nor can column widths without Javascript. Nor can CSS detect overflow.

Comment: Maybe using `grid-template-columns` or `grid-template-rows` :`min-content` or
`max-content` will do. Also take a look at `fit-content`

Comment: In your first example, you say "Flexible column width. Flow in rows" but also ask not to hardcode a number of columns. These two things are mutually exclusive. If the maximum number of columns is three, it has to be said. Is that still within your requirements? Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @enxaneta, I am afraid, it doesn't work. If it worked for you, maybe you could share a fiddle?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier, in the examples, as I have noted, I had to use fixed number of columns simply to demonstrate the desired outcome. The goal is for the number of columns and their widths to be determined automatically based on the available container width and calculated widths of the cells.

Comment: @Tigran Yes, sorry for being thick, but there is a logical impossibility in what I understand of your question. How can it flow in rows before reaching viewport full width? For instance, in the first example, why are all the cells not on the same line? What does "flow in rows" mean if not "reach for the next row when you hit the viewport full width"? Is the green frame supposed to represent the full viewport?

Comment: Or, differently put, can you describe, with words, your requirements **without** using the word three? If you can't there is a high chance that the requirements do not actually amount to something real, a little bit like "seven perpendicular lines".